# Why do I need to name my connection string as "DefaultConnection" to create database MDF file?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I wonder what's going on: if my connection string name is something other than `DefaultConnection`, then the `.mdf` file will not be created in the `App_data` folder, and the database will be created with the name `efaultConnection` as it appear when I go to SQL Server.

If I rename the connection string to `DefaultConnection`, then the `.mdf` file will be created in the `App_data` folder and I will not see the database in SQL Server using SQL Server Management Studio.

By the way, the database will be created once I try to create new user using Identity Framework.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\JobsWebsiteDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: That is pretty much how Entity Framework works.

Comment: See this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813374/how-do-i-setup-asp-net-identity-to-use-my-own-connection-string

Answer (score 0):

You don't, at least I didn't. When you create your DB context, you will need to pass the name of your connection string. For example, my connection string is named "LonelyCacheIdentity":

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, long, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("LonelyCacheIdentity")
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>().Configure(property => property.HasColumnType("datetime2"));
    }
}
```

Then, in my web.config, I have the following connection strings defined:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="LonelyCacheConnection" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=lonelycacheproject;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="LonelyCacheIdentity" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=lonelycacheproject;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

For production, I transform the connection strings to work on the production server.