# How can I store AspNetUser table in a certain SQL Database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I created an MVC Web Application and tried to add a Facebook authentication feature. As expected, when I log in using my Facebook account, AspNetUser tables get auto-generated and filled in a local db called DefaultConnection.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4sRS.png)

What steps should I take in order to be able to save the AspNet tables on a certain SQL Database and not on the temp copy from VS?

Comment: Did you try to change connection string to your SQL connection.

Comment: You need to change the connection string in your `web.config` file to point to the server/db you want to use

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I setup ASP.NET Identity to use my own connection string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813374/how-do-i-setup-asp-net-identity-to-use-my-own-connection-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supply the correct connection string. If it's an ASP.Net web application, this should be supplied in your web.config file.

If it's an ASP.NET CORE web app, this should be in the appsettings.json file.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept this answer so your question is closed! :-)